# Select the View causes TDWM error. Bad Explain Plan? Rootcause?

Tags: sql, performance, teradata

Can anybody help me to tune View based on Explain Plan?

Selecting View cause `TDWM` Error. It is using more than >100k CPU. 
For me it is hard to read Explain Plan in `Teradata` so can you guys help me to resolve the issue?

I have Primary Index `IDN` as well as Secondary Index `PARENT_ID`.

```
 This query is optimized using type 2 profile nonested_cost, profileid
 10003.
  1) First, we lock 'table_name' in view 'view_name' in TD_MAP1 for read 
     on a reserved RowHash to prevent global deadlock.
  2) Next, we lock 'table_name' in view 'view_name' in TD_MAP1 for read.
  3) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step in TD_MAP1 from 'table_name' in view
     'view_name' by way of an all-rows scan with a condition of (
     "'table_name' in view 'view_name'.A = 'X'") into Spool 7 (all_amps), 
     which is redistributed by the hash code of ('table_name'.IDN) to all 
     AMPs in TD_Map1.  Then we do a SORT to order Spool 7 by row hash.  
     The size of Spool 7 is estimated with high confidence to be 562,323 
     rows (16,307,367 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.07 
     seconds.
  4) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step in TD_MAP1 from 'table_name' in view
     'view_name' by way of a RowHash match scan with a condition of (
     "((CAST(('table_name' in view 'view_name'.DATE) AS DATE))>=DATE 
     '2018-01-01') AND (('table_name' in view 'view_name'.A IN ('X','Y',
     'Z')) AND ('table_name' in view 'view_name'.C <> 'XXX'))"), which 
     is joined to Spool 7 (Last Use) by way of a RowHash match scan.
     'table_name' and Spool 7 are joined using a merge join, with a join 
     condition of ("'table_name'.PARENT_ID = IDN").  The result goes into 
     Spool 6 (all_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs.  The size of 
     Spool 6 is estimated with low confidence to be 562,323 rows 
     (308,715,327 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.03 
     seconds.
  5) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step in TD_Map1 from Spool 6 by way of
     an all-rows scan with a condition of ("(NOT (R.K0 IS NULL )) AND
     ((NOT (R.K2 IS NULL )) AND (R.K0D <= R.K2D ))") into Spool 2
     (all_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs.  The size of Spool
     2 is estimated with no confidence to be 562,323 rows (308,715,327
     bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.04 seconds.
  6) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step in TD_Map1 from Spool 6 (Last Use)
     by way of an all-rows scan with a condition of (
     "TD_RECURSIVE_REF.DEPTH <= 264") into Spool 8 (all_amps), which is
     redistributed by the hash code of (
    'table_name'.IDN)
     to all AMPs in TD_Map1.  The size of Spool 8 is estimated with no
     confidence to be 562,323 rows (297,468,867 bytes).  The estimated
     time for this step is 0.14 seconds.
  7) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step in TD_MAP1 from 'table_name' in view
     'view_name' by way of an all-rows scan with a condition of (
     "'table_name' in view 'view_name'.PLANT IN ('X','Y,'Z')"), which 
     is joined to Spool 8 (Last Use) by way of an all-rows scan.
    'table_name' and Spool 8 are joined using a single partition hash 
     join, with a join condition of ("K1 ='table_name'.ID"). The result 
     goes into Spool 9 (all_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs.  
     The size of Spool 9 is estimated with no confidence to be 562,323 
     rows (308,715,327 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.06 
     seconds.
  8) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step in TD_Map1 from Spool 9 (Last Use)
     by way of an all-rows scan into Spool 6 (all_amps), which is built
     locally on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 6 is estimated with no
     confidence to be 28,678,473 rows (15,744,481,677 bytes).  The
     estimated time for this step is 0.04 seconds.  If one or more rows
     are inserted into spool 6, then go to step 5.
  9) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step in TD_Map1 from Spool 2 (Last Use)
     by way of an all-rows scan with a condition of ("(NOT (R.K0 IS
     NULL )) AND ((NOT (R.K2 IS NULL )) AND (R.K0D <= R.K2D ))") into
     Spool 5 (all_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs.  The size
     of Spool 5 is estimated with no confidence to be 28,678,473 rows (
     14,253,201,081 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 1.56
     seconds.
 10) We do an all-AMPs STAT FUNCTION step in TD_Map1 from Spool 5 (Last
     Use) by way of an all-rows scan into Spool 12 (Last Use), which is
     assumed to be redistributed by value to all AMPs in TD_Map1.  The
     result rows are put into Spool 10 (all_amps), which is built
     locally on the AMPs.  The size is estimated with no confidence to
     be 28,678,473 rows (14,482,628,865 bytes).
 11) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step in TD_Map1 from Spool 10 (Last
     Use) by way of an all-rows scan into Spool 3 (used to materialize
     view, derived table, table function or table operator X)
     (all_amps), which is redistributed by the hash code of (Field_35
     (INTEGER), Field_34, K2D, K2Q, K2DI, K2MU, K2MT, K2MN, K2M, K2BD,
     K2PSN, K2PUN, K2MCN, K2MC, K2BN, K2PN, K2PC, K0D, K0Q, K0DI, K0MU,
     K0MT, K0MN, K0M, K0BD, K0PSN, K0PUN, K0MCN, K0MC, K0BN, K0PN, K0PC,
     K2, K0) to all AMPs in TD_Map1.  Then we do a SORT to order Spool
     3 by the sort key in spool field1 eliminating duplicate rows.  The
     size of Spool 3 is estimated with no confidence to be 21,508,855
     rows (35,554,137,315 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is
     7.09 seconds.
 12) We do an all-AMPs SUM step in TD_Map1 to aggregate from Spool 3
     (Last Use) by way of an all-rows scan with a condition of (
     "X.END_LAST_MOVE = 1"), and the grouping identifier in field
     1.  Aggregate Intermediate Results are computed globally, then
     placed in Spool 4 in TD_Map1.  The size of Spool 4 is estimated
     with no confidence to be 16,131,642 rows (25,504,126,002 bytes).
     The estimated time for this step is 38.74 seconds.
 13) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.
  -> The contents of Spool 4 are sent back to the user as the result of
     statement 1.
```

Comment: Please post your query and the `DDL` of the tables used in your query.  If you're just doing a `SELECT * FROM my_view`, then run a `SHOW VIEW my_view;` and paste the results here.  That will allow us to see how best to optimize the query.

Comment: Hi @ravoli, unfortunately I am not allowed to publish View DDL..

Comment: If you got access to the QueryLog you should check dbc.QryLogStepsV for this query to find the failing step. This will allow you to determine which part (recursion or OLAP or the final aggregation) is causing the 100k CPU error.

Comment: @dnoeth I don't have access to dbc.QryLogStepsV

Comment: What are your DBA’s able to suggest since they won’t let you have access to DBQL and your unable to provide DDL/SQL? Can the recursion be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your query and the underlying tables / structures, here are some general tips:

- tweak the underlying view SQL to do any joins, aggregations (i.e. `GROUP BY`) or `OLAP` functions based on the PI columns of those tables (i.e. in Step 10, you have `all-AMPs STAT FUNCTION` which suggests an `OLAP, SAMPLE, or TOP` function)
- there is a reference to `TD_RECURSIVE_REF.DEPTH <= 264`, which suggests you have a recursive query; if you can, try to lower the "depth" value
- Six of the steps in your `EXPLAIN` say "no confidence", so it may be useful to do a `DIAGNOSTIC HELPSTATS ON FOR SESSION;` and then run an `EXPLAIN` on your query.  At the bottom of the `EXPLAIN` you will get a list of recommended statistics to collect.  Run the `EXPLAIN`, collect some of the statistics, then run the `EXPLAIN` again afterwards to see if the query plan changed
- collect statistics on any secondary indexes to increase the chance of them being used

Here are some general physical tuning tips:

- select primary index columns for access and even distribution
- look at value-based compression (smaller rows --> less I/O and spool)
- look at primary index partitioning (PPI), if feasible

Comment: DIAGNOSTIC HELPSTATS ON FOR SESSION; and then explain doesn't show recommended statistics

Comment: Make sure you run the `DIAGNOSTIC` first and then the `EXPLAIN`, both in the same session.  There should be some recommendations appended to the end of the `EXPLAIN`.  Here's an example: https://www.dwhpro.com/teradata-diagnostic-helpstats/

Comment: DIAGNOSTIC HELPSTATS ON FOR SESSION;
EXPLAIN SELECT * my_view; <--- I don't get recommended stats